# How to add a view to a super class view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I have a UIViewController `Car` that is a subclass of another UIViewController `Vehicle`.

```
class Vehicle: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let vehicleLabel = UILabel()
        vehicleLabel.text = "This is the Vehicle"
        view.addSubview(vehicleLabel)
    }
}

class Car: Vehicle {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let carLabel = UILabel()
        carLabel.text = "This is the Car"
        super.view.addSubview(carLabel)
    }
}

// called like this

let carController = Car()
presentViewController(carController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

From `Car` I would like to add a UILabel to the `Vehicle` top level view. However all my attempts at this end up adding it to the `Car` view instead.

I've tried directly accessing the parent view:

```
super.view.addSubview(carLabel)
```

also tried creating a function to add views on Vehicle:

```
func addToSuperView(label: UILabel){
    self.view.addSubview(label)
}
```

also tried playing with `superclass` but failed. I end up with this, where the labels are on the view associated with the view of the UIViewController where they were created. I'd like both labels on `Vehicle`.

[image: Exploded View]

[image: Tree]

How do I do this?

Comment: If you have a *subclass* your car view is the same as the vehicle view. Show some more code of `Car` or `Vehicle` for anyone to be of more help.

Comment: When you create an instance of `Car` there is no instance of `Vehicle` created but it sounds as if you are instantiating a `Vehicle` and need a `Car` instance inside.. is that right?

Comment: The reason of failure is the instance of your subclass is created. It has not created any instance of your super class.

Comment: @luk2302 Please see my edits.

Comment: @FlorianWeßling I get the instances I would expect, but am trying to assign a view from the child to the parent VC. Please see my edits.

Comment: That image does not reflect what you are showing in code, are you talking about super (inheritance) or parent/child which is something ENTIRELY different!?

Comment: For me it sounds like you are mixing up subclasses (inheritance) and subviews (hierarchy of views). Could you add a few lines of the code where you create the `Car` and `Vehicle` instances? In general you need to pass the reference to the `Vehicle` when creating the `Car` and then access it from `Car`.

Comment: @luk2302 Inheritance. The Vehicle VC has a base view that I'm adding a label to. The Car VC inherits from Vehicle. You see in the image that each VC has its own view in the hierarchy (labeled accordingly). Instead of Car adding a label to the Car view, I want to access the superclass view (Vehicle) and set a label there.

Comment: **`self.view` is the same as `super.view`** since view is a property of `super`.

Comment: @matt So the exploded view presented by XCode and posted here is misleading? There are clearly two separate UIViews, one created by Vehicle and one created by Car. Is that not a true statement?

Comment: @matt Further evidence added there are SEPARATE UIViews created by Car and Vehicle. Me thinks I'm not the one with a misunderstanding of OO here.

Comment: Vehicle, Car should be models, not VCs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

The exploded view isn't what you should be looking at, because the most frequently used UIKit classes have a number of wrapper views and container views that are used by the classes privately.

What you can be certain of is that no instance of Vehicle or its view can exist, because you haven't coded for it. Notice also the view hierarchy - there is only one label, not two.

Comment: Car is a subclass of Vehicle. Vehicle does not present Car. This won't work.

Comment: @Fook, then which view-controller presents Car? Which view-controller instantiates Vehicle?

Comment: There is a VC called GarageViewController that presents Car. Vehicle is not directly instantiated. Vehicle does render a UIView though, and that is the view I'm trying to access. See my updated images of the exploded view.

Comment: If Vehicle is not instantiated, then it does not exist either in memory or in the view hierarchy. `super.view` in Car simply refers to its own `self.view`. They are both the same object. Try to print the description of `self.view` and `super.view` and compare the memory addresses.

Comment: I agree that `self.view` and `super.view` are the same reference. However look at the exploded view and the tree above. There are two separate `UIViews` being created, one from each controller. `Car` and it's contents sit at a higher z-index than `Vehicle`. XCode seems to be showing these as two `UIViews`, or is XCode presenting this incorrectly?

Comment: The exploded view isn't what you should be looking at, because the most frequently used UIKit classes have a number of wrapper views and container views that are used by the classes privately. What you can be certain of is that no instance of Vehicle or its view can exist, because you haven't coded for it. Notice also the view hierarchy - there is only one label, not two.

Comment: THAT answers my question! The diagram was misleading. Thank you. Can you post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

A "super.view" is NOT IDENTICAL with your parent UIViewController's view.

A "super.view" is something in a view hierarchy.
A parent or child is something in a class inheritance.

Both things are quite different!

*remark: UpperCaseWriting = ONLY for marking purposes (to accentuate key arguments)*

Comment: Understood, though Vehicle does seem to create it's own UIView as shown in the screenshots above. That is the view I'm trying to access.

Comment: @matt VC inheritance is not misusing UIViewControllers. You seem angry. In fact you seem angry in 90% of the questions you respond to on this site. Go away. Your nerd rage isn't welcome here.

Answer (score 1):

@Fook, For Car to add a UILabel to its superview, in this case Vehicle, Car must be a subclass of UIView (not UIViewController or Vehicle) and must be added as a subview to Vehicle's view. Then Car can add a UILabel to its superview with:

```
Car.superview?.addSubview(UILabel())
```

If Car must inherit from UIViewController or Vehicle then Car must be presented by Vehicle. It doesn't matter whether Car inherits from Vehicle or not. Then Car can add a subview to its the view controller that presents it by saying:

```
presentingViewController?.view.addSubview(UILabel())
```

Comment: OK, so it sounds like in my case there is no way to access the Vehicle UIView from Car (shown in the screenshot above), given that Car inherits from Vehicle? I can't get a handle on that Vehicle UIView somehow?